# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el ID de un elemento especifico a partir de su clase css?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

Necesito obtener el ID del elemento cuando el TextBox obtiene el foco e imprimirlo en la consola ***¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?*** , escribí un código pero siempre imprime **txt00**

Tengo esto en el HTML:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt00" class="cTxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>        
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt01" class="cTxt" runat="server></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt02" class="cTxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Codigo JQuery:

```
 $('.cTxt').focus(function () {
            var id = $('.cTxt').attr('ID');
            console.log(id);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas jQuery dentro de la función, mejor usa el objeto contexto `this`:

```
$('.cTxt').focus(
   function(){
      var id = this.id;
      console.log(id);
   }
);
```

Comment: Hola Sal ... lo mismo siempre escribe txt00

Comment: Omití un detalle, actualicé la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

El callback que envias a focus, como todo handler para un elemento del DOM que recibe un evento, se le pasa como argumento un objeto Event, ese objeto mantiene una referencia al elemento que acaba de disparar el evento. y así podrías obtener el `id` en vez de volver a usar la función de Jquery para seleccionar.

Usando una clase de ejemplo que me invente, así seria la solución:

```
let elementClass = $(".p")

elementClass.focus(function(evt){
  alert(evt.target.id)
})
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Usando un ejemplo como el que tienes:

```js
let elementClass = $(".00-1")

elementClass.focus(function(evt){
  alert(evt.target.id)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="00-1" id="1">
<input type="text" class="00-1" id="2">
<input type="text" class="00-1" id="3">
```